# Check if a value exists in map using an internal function from that struct

Tags: go, go-map

I've this struct

```
type Zones map[uint64]Zone
```

And I want to have a method to find a value in that map, something like this.

```
func (z *Zones) findById(id uint64) (Zone, error) {
    if zone, ok := z[id]; ok {
        return zone, nil
    } else {
        return zone{}, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Zone %d not found", id))
    }
}
```

But in this line:

```
if zone, ok := z[id]; ok {
```

I'm getting this error:

> Assignment count mismatch: 2=1.

Theres a lot of links which suggest that we can check if a value exists in a map with that line, I have no idea what is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error you should be getting is `invalid operation: z[id] (type *Zones does not support indexing)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `*Zone` does not support indexing. It's a pointer, not a map.  Dereference the pointer to fix the code:

```
func (z *Zones) findById(id uint64) (Zone, error) {
    if zone, ok := (*z)[id]; ok { // <-- note change on this line
        return zone, nil
    } else {
        return Zone{}, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Zone %d not found", id))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)